wxpython error while trying to build and run GRASS in Docker from source code
I have tried for a full day to build and run GRASS from source code using Docker, and I am not able to succeed. I am interested in building and running this way to potentially contribute.
Here is what I have tried:
Environment: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

Forked the main branch and cloned my fork locally.
Followed the instructions in the README to build with:
docker build -t grassgis .
Followed the instructions in the README to run with:

xhost local:$(id -u)
docker run -it --privileged --user=$(id -u):$(id -g) --rm \
    --volume="$(pwd)/:/data" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
    --env HOME=/data/ --env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    --device="/dev/dri/card0:/dev/dri/card0" \
    grassgis grass --gui

I ran into many issues that I believe I have resolved, but I can't get the gui to load. I get the following errors:
WARNING: It appears that the X Windows system is not active.
A graphical based user interface is not supported.
(DISPLAY variable is not set.)
Switching to text based interface mode.

And then when I try g.gui wxpython:
ERROR: wxGUI requires wxPython. libsecret-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have verified that wxpython is installed in the python path. What am I doing wrong?

If this is related to GRASS GIS then I think you should start your question body by mentioning that.

You followed the build instructions for "A. Docker image without graphical user interface - wxGUI.". Perhaps try the instructions for "B. Docker image with graphical user interface - wxGUI." i.e. docker build -t grassgis -f docker/ubuntu_wxgui/Dockerfile . 

And what is the output of ls /dev/dri/ on your Ubuntu 24.04 host? I have card1 not card0 but I'm running 22.04.
